# PHP + MYSQL SUM between same field value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on work order progress system.

I have this query:

```
SELECT c.sheet_no
     , c.step
     , a.crew_est
     , a.manhour_est
     , c.act_hours
  FROM work_sheet_machine a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN machine_master_data b 
    ON a.machine_code = b.code
  JOIN daily_activity_control_card-man c 
    ON c.wo_number = a.wo_number
   AND c.sheet_no = a.sheet
   AND c.step = a.serial
  LEFT 
  JOIN machine_master_data d 
    ON c.machine_code = d.code
 WHERE a.wo_number = 'I7474549';
```

MYSQL return me this result:

```
+----------+------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| sheet_no | step | crew_est | manhour_est | act_hours |
+----------+------+----------+-------------+-----------+
|        1 |    1 |        1 |         0.5 |        35 |
|        1 |    2 |        2 |           2 |        11 |
|        1 |    2 |        2 |           2 |        11 |
|        1 |    3 |        2 |           3 |        11 |
+----------+------+----------+-------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The result is good, but I need to get **total_act_hours** for each same step number, so the result I need to get is look like this (please click run code snippet to see the result):

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td> sheet_no </td>
<td> step </td>
<td> crew_est </td>
<td> manhour_est </td>
<td> act_hours </td>
<td> total_act_hours </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> 0.5 </td>
<td> 35 </td>
<td> 35 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> 2 </td>
<td> 2 </td>
<td> 2 </td>
<td> 11 </td>
<td rowspan="2"> 11 </td>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> 2 </td>
<td> 2 </td>
<td> 2 </td>
<td> 11 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> 3 </td>
<td> 2 </td>
<td> 2 </td>
<td> 3 </td>
<td> 11 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I achieve this in MYSQL query or MYSQL + PHP code?

Anyhelp will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add sub-querys and at the sum into you're query. [Watch here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/subqueries/index.php)